# Keep track of follow/unfollow events django

Tags: django

I am building a sort of social media app, where users can follow certain pages. I want the page managers to be able to visualize their followers in a chart for each day/week or so. So I am thinking about how to implement the following system. For now, I have this model:

```
class FollowHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follow_history")
    page = models.ForeignKey('Page', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower_history")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    followed = models.BooleanField()
```

When a user clicks Follow, I create an instance with `followed = True`, and the timestamp of the event. When a user clicks Unfollow, I do the same, but with `followed = False`.

I am struggling to figure out how to query the data in a way for a page to see how many followers they had each day. So far I have tried this:

```
FollowHistory.objects.filter(page=page, followed=True)\
.annotate(ts_day=Trunc('timestamp', 'day'))\
.values('ts_day')\
.annotate(followers=Count('id'))
```

But that just gives me the count of events that happened in a day, so if I follow and unfollow a company 10 times, then it will count 10 times. I only need to know by the end of the day, did I follow or not?

Maybe there is a better implementation of the model that you could recommend, I am open to that too. Thanks!

**Update:**

I managed to set up a query that outputs the change in number of followers each day:

```
FollowHistory.objects.filter(page=page)\
.values('timestamp')\
.annotate(followings=(Count(Case(When(followed=True, then=1)))-Count(Case(When(followed=False, then=1)))))\
.order_by('timestamp')
```

Where `followings` calculates the difference between follows and unfollows for each day.

The result is something like this:

| date | followings |
| --- | --- |
| 28.02.2022 | 1 |
| 01.03.2022 | 3 |
| 04.03.2022 | -1 |
| 05.03.2022 | 2 |
| 08.03.2022 | 0 |

So there are still a few problems with this:

1. I need the cumulative sum, so a column that goes 1, 4, 3, 5, 5
2. How would I fill in the missing dates when no one follows or unfollows?
3. On the 8th of march, followings equals 0 because someone followed and later unfollowed a page.

I don't know if I should stick with this approach or just find another way to set up the FollowHistory model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create two queries:

```
people_who_unfollowed = FollowHistory.objects.filter(timestamp__year=2022, timestamp__month=03, timestamp__day=12,page=page, followed=False)
people_who_followed   = FollowHistory.objects.filter(timestamp__year=2022, timestamp__month=03, timestamp__day=12,page=page, followed=True)
```

now your output for 12 march 2022 will be:

```
followings = len(people_who_followed) - len(people_who_unfollowed)
```

or there is `another approach`:

```
class FollowHistory(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follow_history")
   page = models.ForeignKey('Page', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower_history")
   timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   counter = models.IntegerField()
```

when any user wants to follow or unfollow:

```
today = date.today()
get_or_create_Follow_history_object, created = FollowHistory.objects.get_or_create(timestamp__year=today.year, timestamp__month=today.monnh, timestamp__day=today.day,page=page)
if created == True:
    # here is some logic with created FollowHistory object
    # you need to up or down counter of this model
    # get_or_create_Follow_history_object.counter = get_or_create_Follow_history_object.counter + 1 #(or-1 if unfollow)
    # get_or_create_Follow_history_object.save()
else:
    # this is for object which already exists
    # get_or_create_Follow_history_object.counter = get_or_create_Follow_history_object.counter + 1 #(or-1 if unfollow)
    # get_or_create_Follow_history_object.save()
```

this will get FollowHistory if it is exists and `created` variable will be `False`,

if it doesnt exist, it will be created, and `created` variable will be `True`

at the end of the day you will have many `FollowHistory` objects wich will correspond on how many follows/unfollows happend (.counter property) and its date, so you can make a query:

```
all_follow_history_objects = FollowHistory.objects.filter(page=page, user=user)
```

and send it to your html page, where you can output all data in table in for loop

```
{% for i in all_follow_history_objects %}
    <p>date: {{i.timestamp}} ---  counter: {{i.counter}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this seems like a nice solution. However, how would you recommend to handle the dates when no follow/unfollow events happen? If I want to plot the number of followers for the last 7 days for example

Comment: i prefer method with counter, if you want output query for last 7 days it might be `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` ///// `one_week_ago_time = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)` ///// `one_week_objects = FollowHistory.objects.filter(page=page, user=user, timestamp__gte=one_week_ago_time)` here you will get all your objects for a week, and in for loop you can count all .counter properties

Comment: that makes sense, but it will output only the dates where there is an object. so if yesterday no one followed, then that date will not be shown at all. how would i fill in the missing dates with a value of 0 followings?

Comment: this is a good question i can suggest only a way to think: 1st you might mannually create this object, you can change `user` and `page` property `blank=True, null=True`, for example you at 23.00 (cron) script might check if objects on pages exist, if not create object with only `timestamp` and `counter = 0` this is not good solution but it will work

Comment: `2nd variant` is more appropriate: for example you have a week table, but you have only 4 objects, you might create a dictionary, in which you would with for loop add key(date) and value(counter), and check with if condition, `if the date` start with `1st day`, and `day1+1day = 2nd day` - okay, `if not` `add to dictionary current date(key) and counter = 0(value), and continue`. Then send dictionary on your page. This should work, and it doesn't create unnecessary data in your database. But implimentation is up to you, i never did this, but concept is legit.

Comment: Thank you, the second variant sounds reasonable